# Dropzone - Add extra values (hidden fields) to images

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am integrating DropZones.js with Laravel 5.2. So far so good. The only thing is that on upload, I would like to add extra hidden fields to the image container.

```
<div class="dz-preview ">
  <img src="" />
</div>

<div class="dz-preview ">
  <img src="" />
</div>
<div class="dz-preview ">
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

**And I would like:**

```
<div class="dz-preview ">
  <img src="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="imagehidden1" . . . >
</div>

<div class="dz-preview ">
  <img src="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="imagehidden2" . . . >
</div>

<div class="dz-preview ">
  <img src="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="imagehidden3" . . . >
</div>
```

In other words, I want to add 3 hidden fields if I add 3 images, 5 if I add 5 and so forth, each with its own unique **name**.

Anyone?

Comment: What is the purpose for that hidden input? Do you want to POST that extra data with each file, or do you want to have that hidden input exist in the DOM for some other reason?

Comment: The upload is part of a serialized form and I want to submit the images as part of that array.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to submit the actual images alongside the other form data? I never got that to work properly myself, and decided to just do the dynamic upload built-in to dropzone. I think the difficulty is that an actual file input is read only for security reasons. So, you would have to generate a FormData object and submit that with javascript, rather than the default submit, I think.

Comment: Yea. That's exactly what I need to do. I know I will get it eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging and found that that one of the templates **previewTemplate**. I replace that value with my updated HTML version with the hidden inputs :) like so:

```
Dropzone.options.falcondropzone = {
    previewsContainer     : ".dropzone-previews",
    thumbnailWidth        : "400",
    thumbnailHeight       : "200",
    maxFiles              : 10,
    maxFilesize           : 5000,
    clickable             : '.roundedicon',
    previewTemplate       : '<input type="hidden" name="uploadables[]" class="uploadedimg" /> . . . . . .  }
```

That worked for me. I hope it helps someone some day